# How can I find out when a model changes with Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Considering below class. Is it possible to listen for whenever `appStateModel.bar` changes? I have a scenario where I want to perform an animation every time a certain value changes, but I can't seem to figure out how to achieve that.

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appStateModel = Provider.of<AppStateModel>(context);
    return Container(
      child: Text('${appStateModel.bar}'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `notifyListeners()` method when changing the bar property.

Comment: That is already done. The value updates just fine. It's just I want to know when the update was performed so I can act on it.

Comment: Your text widget will automatically be updated when you call notifyListeners().

Answer (score 0):

In your change notifier, you should include `notifyListeners()` as stated.
With that, it should work.

On the other hand, you can use the build method to act on change events because the widget will rebuild every time `notifyListeners()` is called (At least at my point of understanding).

If that won't work, there is the Consumer Widget, it consumes a notifier and rebuilds only if `notifyListeners()` is called.
This widget also provides a child parameter with which you can save performance when using it because it does not need to rebuild when the notifier changes.

I hope this resolves your issue.